# MPS - Standalone repl application?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, mps

Continuing my exploration of possibilities MPS can offer, I wonder, is it possible to extract MPS repl component/module into some standalone application which would use some external model files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that extracting components from MPS would be really complicate. While it is feasible to basically strip down MPS and get a more focused IDE, just getting out a component does not seem easy. MPS is a massive piece of technology with a lot of dependency. What you can do easily is to edit models in MPS and then generate some other format to be processed outside MPS. You can also write some code to read the MPS format (it is just some convoluted XML after all). But getting a component out seems hard.

Source: I am using MPS since several years, currently consulting most of my time on MPS